# Connectivity Issues That Service Provider Can't Answer

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ssh, iphone

hello I'm not very tech savvy and I have a few questions in regards to my internet service that my provider seems unable to answer. I WAH between different contracts which some require higher speeds  etc I upgraded my already crappy service to meet software requirements to move forward on new project. I noticed a new private network displayed in my iPhone's "My Networks" section that I don't have access to nor did I authorize. Xfinity insists its the "public hotspot " broadcast. Public is "xfinitywifi" NOT SECURE and NOT in my "MY Networks". "XFINITY" SECURED  displays as a private network on my network. Why do I have 2 private networks, 1 I cant access and 2 my primary, displaying on my iphone but not in router admin? So I want to understand why I'm paying $100+ a month with ONE gateway rental and 2 private networks and still have horrible unstable connectivity. I live in an upstairs apt  and distance between my gateway and the main outside box is less than 20ft its located directly below. I use 1 ethernet  cable and no more than 3 smart devices. Above topic/questions are only few of many I would like answers and or clarification. From info gathered from various forums possibly indicate 'Man In The Middle" among other things. I keep records/logs screenshots if it would help to provide answers just let me know and I will post them. Thank you

Comment: Wcome to SU. This wall of text is really hard to read and confusing. You may get better answers if you break it into paragraphs, ask clear questions and dont use words like WAH. Also, you may want to remove judgements from your post as it makes you look like you are venting and looking to blame parties rather then curious and trying to understand.  Also, consider breaking it up into multiple posts - you appear to have a performance issue which is likely distinct from your Wifi one.

Comment: @davidgo, Comcast is a incompetent ISP. I deal with clients all the time who have BYOB Comcast connections, most installs aren't even to their own installation standards... Leaving customers angry and confused, and yes the give the customer the run around. A couple days ago I was dealing with an xfinity "gigabit" connection. When I showed up it was testing out @ 12/3 Mbps up/down, and dropping out for 5-10 minutes at a time. I would be pissed too.

Answer (score 1):

I'll try pick out and rephrase what I think are the questions and provide some answers:

Q: What are the "xfinitywifi" (unsecured) and "XFINITY" (secured) wireless networks?

A: These are 2 networks that any Xfinity (and some others) customers can use when they are not at home. As an Xfinity customer, by default your equipment is making your Internet available to these other people to use for free. More information on this can be found [here](https://www.xfinity.com/support/articles/about-xfinity-wifi-internet).

Q: Are these wireless networks impacting my Internet speed?

A: It's possible but not very likely. But you can test by disabling these networks by following [these instructions](https://www.xfinity.com/support/articles/disable-xfinity-wifi-home-hotspot).

Q: Why is my Internet so unstable?

A: This is very difficult to know as there are many possibilities. A good place to start is to check the results from https://fast.com/ when standing right next to your wireless router and see what that says. If those numbers look fine, try again when you move around your apartment and see if there are places where it's good and less good. Once you know that and can describe what you're seeing, we can look at the next options.